# How Would You Install LVM CentOS 7 In A Contabo VPS Environment?

Tags: centos, centos7, vps, lvm

I currently use a Contabo M SSD VPS and I am looking to get CentOS 7 installed with LVM for the system partition. However, there is not a direct route to do this since Contabo's OS images are all non-LVM. One path I see around this is using their SystemRecovery image and manually STP'ing over the CentOS ISO and... besides [installing the OS like so](http://www.techspacekh.com/minimal-rhelcentos-7-installation-with-logical-volume-manager-lvm/con), getting there is where my expertise in doing something like this ends. I ask this because I would like to do daily "hot" snapshots to the cloud in the event that my system unexpectedly gave up the ghost. As it is, given that I am on a non-LVM install of CentOS, I am currently forced to do Duplicacy incremental backups of a selection of folders (/etc, /home, /opt, /root, /srv, /usr, /var) as well as separate daily backups of my WordPress and Discourse sites, all of which are pushed daily (or more) to the cloud. Though I have documentation completely written out with all the steps I would need to follow to rebuild my VPS, a full from-the-ground-up recovery is a lot more laborious than having to simply restore a snapshot. Before going officially live, I did a from-the-ground-up recovery twice as a sort of self-inflicted fire drill to ensure it would work out but I would much rather have a system snapshot solution in place. Thoughts and advice?

Note: I have crossposted this help request on Reddit [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/selfhosted/comments/bpvsyr/how_would_you_install_lvm_centos_7_in_a_contabo/) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/bpw1hw/how_would_you_install_lvm_centos_7_in_a_contabo/).

Answer (score 0):

Bingo! After scouring the web, I finally found a workable solution on GitHub:

https://gist.github.com/AndersonIncorp/28aabd6be1a43199ee1bd27d1bcfd654

Comment: So what is the solution?